# How do I get every character after a segment in my column in R?

Tags: r, regex, data-manipulation

`Fake City, TX Court House`

I would like to return:
`Court House`

This is what I have from another post. I used it to be able to extract the city piece.

```
gsub(",.*$", "", COLUMN$Entity)
```

My gut tells me that ",.*$ will have to change but I'm not sure what to change it to.

I'm new to regular expressions. Thank you, guys.

Comment: We could capture comma and spcae `TX ` with `, [A-Z]{2}`:  `gsub("^.*, [A-Z]{2} ", "", COLUMN$Entity)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try

```r
# Input string
input_string <- 'Fake City, TX Court House'

# Use regular expression to extract 'Court House'
extracted_text <- gsub('.*\\,\\s\\w+\\s', '', input_string)


[1] "Court House"
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
x <- c("Fake City, TX Court House", "Fake City, TX")
sub(".*\\b[A-Z]{2}\\b\\s?", "", x)
# [1] "Court House" ""
```

---

R has a built in character vector of state abbreviations. We can use this to construct a regular expression to split the string on the state abbreviation and take everything after it.

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c("Fake City, TX Court House",
       "Fake City, OK Court House",
       "Fake City, PA",
       "CArlsbad, CA Court House")

str_split_i(x, str_c("\\b", state.abb, "\\b\\s", collapse = "|"), 2)
# [1] "Court House" "Court House" NA            "Court House"
```

This is what the regular expression looks like ("match the word 'AL" followed by a space *or* the word 'AK' followed by a space..."):

```r
str_c("\\b", state.abb, "\\b\\s", collapse = "|")
"\\bAL\\b\\s|\\bAK\\b\\s|\\bAZ\\b\\s|\\bAR\\b\\s|\\bCA\\b\\s|\\bCO\\b\\s|\\bCT\\b\\s|\\bDE\\b\\s|\\bFL\\b\\s|\\bGA\\b\\s|\\bHI\\b\\s|\\bID\\b\\s|\\bIL\\b\\s|\\bIN\\b\\s|\\bIA\\b\\s|\\bKS\\b\\s|\\bKY\\b\\s|\\bLA\\b\\s|\\bME\\b\\s|\\bMD\\b\\s|\\bMA\\b\\s|\\bMI\\b\\s|\\bMN\\b\\s|\\bMS\\b\\s|\\bMO\\b\\s|\\bMT\\b\\s|\\bNE\\b\\s|\\bNV\\b\\s|\\bNH\\b\\s|\\bNJ\\b\\s|\\bNM\\b\\s|\\bNY\\b\\s|\\bNC\\b\\s|\\bND\\b\\s|\\bOH\\b\\s|\\bOK\\b\\s|\\bOR\\b\\s|\\bPA\\b\\s|\\bRI\\b\\s|\\bSC\\b\\s|\\bSD\\b\\s|\\bTN\\b\\s|\\bTX\\b\\s|\\bUT\\b\\s|\\bVT\\b\\s|\\bVA\\b\\s|\\bWA\\b\\s|\\bWV\\b\\s|\\bWI\\b\\s|\\bWY\\b\\"
```

The use of word boundaries `\\b` prevent the state abbreviations from matching other parts of the string (such as the "CA" in CArlsbad).

---

If TX is the only delimiter you care about then this can be simplified:

```r
str_split_i("Fake City, TX Court House", "TX ", 2)
```

A comparable base R solutions:

```r
sapply(strsplit("Fake City, TX Court House", "TX "), `[`, 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hows is this

```
text <- "Fake City, TX Court House"

# Use regular expression to extract "Court House"
result <- sub(".*, TX (.*)", "\\1", text)

# Print the result
print(result)

"Court House"
```